# Nauck-IT PostgreSQL membership provider

Tags: postgresql, membership, provider

I am not able to find any documentation on this product. While the package is still available on 'NUGET' - the web-site for documentation seems to be 'down'.

This is the web-site I'm directed to - but, cannot connect to: http://dev.nauck-it.de/projects/aspsqlprovider

Does anyone have available documentation on this package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may download [NauckIT](https://github.com/dnauck/AspSQLProvider) from GitHub and there you'll find some documentation.

Comment: Communicated with the original developer - he provided this link: https://github.com/dnauck/AspSQLProvider/

Answer (score 1):

Due the migration to a new project management tool the URL has changed to: http://dev.nauck-it.de/projects/aspsqlprovider

If you've any question, let me know.